# Jira jql query to search for tickets that status changed to a particular status after a date

Tags: jira, jql

I need to filter on tickets that went into status a status of RTT after a particular date. These tickets would be resolved now but I need to see all those that entered that status after a date regardless of their current status.

Answer (score 47):

for example, find all issues that their status changed from `Open` to `Closed` after `2012/12/31`:

```
status CHANGED FROM "Open" TO "Closed" AFTER "2012/12/31"
```

you can find for info about `CHANGED` search key on [Atlasian's Advanced Searching page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching#AdvancedSearching-CHANGED).

Comment: This is the best/correct answer, even though it wasn't marked as such.

Answer (score 0):

type = "Bug" AND status was in ("Resolved")